# what is the performance difference of sqlite3_exec() and sqlite3_get_table()

Tags: sqlite

I want to know what is the performance  difference between sqlite3_exec() and sqlite3_get_table().

is there a performance difference...?

Answer (score 3):

As with any performance issue, *measure* your specific use case.

The documentation for `sqlite3_get_table` tells the following:

> This next routine is really just a wrapper around sqlite3_exec().
>   Instead of invoking a user-supplied callback for each row of the
>   result, this routine remembers each row of the result in memory
>   obtained from malloc(), then returns all of the result after the
>   query has finished.

So one could presume that `sqlite3_get_table` performs worse, unless the processing to be done with `sqlite3_exec` directly is similar. How much they actually differ and whether the difference is significant is up to measurements on your data and your code.